# How to calculate percentage from Row total using DAX instead of quick measures

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to get % share of category searches by Month using Row total. I can achieve it by using quick measures, but I want to know the DAX function behind it.

[image: Input]

I have written the following DAX but it gives me 100% for every cell in the matrix table

```
#Share Of SRPV = 
Var AllSRPV = CALCULATE([TotalSrPV], All('Supply Data'[Date-f].[MonthNo]))
Return
DIVIDE([TotalSrPV],AllSRPV)
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Why you still need dax when you already get the result? You image is incorrect result?

Comment: The best way to debug is to change what you return from your Measure. First check what return for you [TotalSrPV], then check what you get from variables AllSRPV; Then probably you find why? Without specification for your measure [TotalSrPV] is hard to tell

Answer (score 2):

You are using Auto date time feature of Power BI for computing values over time, behind the scenes Power BI sorts the Month column by `Dates[Date].[MonthNo]` so that Jan, Feb, and March appear in their logical order and not ascending order based on the text values, because of this operation you see months in order of JFMAMJJASOND (Month initials).

Now, both the columns `Dates[Date].[Month]` & `Dates[Date].[MonthNo]` have the 1:1 relationship, so even though you use `Dates[Date].[Month]`, the column `Dates[Date].[MonthNo]` is cross-filtering `Dates[Date].[Month]`. Thus, for each cell, you are removing the filters using *ALL*, but the cross-filter is messing with your calculations.

If you are only interested in a solution then use this:

```
#Share Of SRPV =
VAR AllSRPV =
    CALCULATE (
        [TotalSrPV],
        ALL ( 'Supply Data'[Date-f].[MonthNo], 'Supply Data'[Date-f].[Month] )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( [TotalSrPV], AllSRPV )
```

To learn more, read further:

First thing to do is to turn off auto date/time, make sure you uncheck the option of date/time in the settings, which is also shown in the below image:

[image: Auto date/time]

Next, you need to create a proper Date table, without a date table never compute values over time; you can do that either in Power Query or create a DAX Calculated Table:

To do in Power Query paste this code in advanced editor:

```
let
    RandomDates = { #date ( 2021, 1, 1 ), #date ( 2018, 3, 6 ), #date ( 2022, 12, 30 ) },
    DateColumnInputTable = InputTable[Date],  // Replace this with the column of any table with the help of which you want to build a date table:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    Source = List.Distinct ( RandomDates ),
    DateList =
        let
            MinDate       = List.Min ( Source ),
            MaxDate       = List.Max ( Source ),
            StartDate     = Number.From ( #date ( Date.Year ( MinDate ), 1, 1 ) ),
            EndDate       = Number.From ( #date ( Date.Year ( MaxDate ), 12, 31 ) ),
            Calendar      = { StartDate .. EndDate },
            ToTable       = Table.FromList ( Calendar, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error ),
            ToDate        = Table.TransformColumnTypes ( ToTable, { "Column1", type date } ),
            ChangeColName = Table.RenameColumns ( ToDate, { { "Column1", "Date" } } )
        in
            ChangeColName,
    MonthName = Table.AddColumn ( DateList, "Month Name", each Date.MonthName ( [Date] ), type text ),
    MonthNumber = Table.AddColumn ( MonthName, "Month Number", each Date.Month ( [Date] ), Int64.Type ),
    CalendarYear = Table.AddColumn ( MonthNumber, "Calendar Year", each Date.Year ( [Date] ), Int64.Type ),
    DayName = Table.AddColumn ( CalendarYear, "Day of Week Name", each Date.DayOfWeekName ( [Date] ), type text ),
    DayNumber = Table.AddColumn ( DayName, "Day of Week Number", each Date.Day ( [Date] ), Int64.Type ),
    MonthShortName = Table.AddColumn ( DayNumber, "Month Initials", each Text.Start ( Date.MonthName ( [Date] ), 3 ), type text ),
    QuarterName = Table.AddColumn ( MonthShortName, "Quarter", each "Q" & Text.From ( Date.QuarterOfYear ( [Date] ) ), type text ),
    QuarterNumber = Table.AddColumn ( QuarterName, "Quarter Number", each Date.QuarterOfYear ( [Date] ), Int64.Type )
in
    QuarterNumber
```

To create DAX Table use this:

```
Dates =
VAR ListOfDate =
    VAR MinDate =
        MIN ( Sales[Order Date] ) -- Change with the column reference of your table
    VAR MaxDate =
        MAX ( Sales[Order Date] ) -- Change with the column reference of your table
    VAR StartDate =
        DATE ( YEAR ( MinDate ), 1, 1 ) -- DATE ( 2021, 1, 1 )
    VAR EndDate =
        DATE ( YEAR ( MaxDate ), 12, 31 ) -- DATE ( 2021, 12, 31 )
    VAR Result =
        CALENDAR ( StartDate, EndDate )
    RETURN
        Result
VAR Result =
    GENERATE (
        ListOfDate,
        VAR CurrentDate = [Date]
        RETURN
            ROW (
                "Month", FORMAT ( CurrentDate, "MMMM" ),
                "Month Number", MONTH ( CurrentDate ),
                "Calendar Year", "CY " & YEAR ( CurrentDate ),
                "Calendar Year Number", YEAR ( CurrentDate )
            )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

Once you are done, mark the date table as a date table.

[image: Mark as date table]

Next let's say you build a report like the following one using the below DAX Code:

```
Total Sales CY = 
CALCULATE ( 
    [Total Sales],
    REMOVEFILTERS ( Dates[Month] )
)
```

[image: Report]

Everything works as you’d expect, but as soon as you sort the Month Name column by Month Number, the calculation stops working.

[image: Month sorted]

Report after sorting:

[image: Broken report]

The problem is that, behind the scenes, Power BI generates the following code, which contains Month Number:

```
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    ROLLUPADDISSUBTOTAL (
        'Dates'[Calendar Year Number],
        "IsGrandTotalRowTotal",
        ROLLUPGROUP ( 'Dates'[Month], 'Dates'[Month Number] ),
        "IsDM1Total"
    ),
    "Total_Sales", 'ReportMeasures'[Total Sales],
    "Total_Sales_CY", 'ReportMeasures'[Total Sales CY]
)
```

To make it easier to read, I am going to remove the functions that compute subtotals/grand totals.

```
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    'Dates'[Calendar Year Number],
    'Dates'[Month],
    'Dates'[Month Number],
    "Total_Sales", [Total Sales],
    "Total_Sales_CY", [Total Sales CY]
)
```

Now you can easily see that Month Number is also used in the `GroupBy` operation, and the `GroupBy` columns are the primary reason for filter context that exists in a visual.

If I comment the Month Number column, I get the correct result:

[image: DAX Studio's result]

If I can somehow prevent that column from filtering the measure inside CALCULATE I can get the result I want; the way to do that is to include the month number column inside ALL/REMOVEFILTERS:

[image: Working report]